# Internal pdf viewer in texmaker pixelated on Mac Sierra

Tags: pdf, texmaker, mac, viewers, pixelated

Using texmaker has always worked fine for me, until I recently changed to an iMac (macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1 (16B2657), Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015). Now, texmaker has a pixelated internal pdf, even though the pdf is not blurry when opening it directly with e.g. Adobe Reader. This question has already been asked [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333963/internal-pdf-viewer-in-texmaker-blurry-on-mac-sierra?rq=1), but was closed before a useful answer was given, so do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It's not a solution, but I encourage you to give a try to texpad! For me, it's the best Mac OS LaTex editor: full features, Mac OS alike user interface, and so on. It costs 20 dollars / euros, but you can download a two-week preview version. (DISCLAIMER: I am not linked to texpad app in any sense; it's just my choice). The link is: https://www.texpad.com.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have used texmaker for many years and really like it! So I would be very happy about any help to fix my problem.